# javax.validation not found in Spring boot 2.3

Tags: spring-boot

After upgrade to Spring Boot 2.3.1 `javax.validation` package not found.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Before it's working fine. Now `imprort javax.validation.Valid;` this import not resolved. Didn't found anything their release also [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.3.1.RELEASE)

Should I need to externally add this package now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the on the release notes of Spring-Boot-2.3

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```